# How to change user & browser settings on Chromebooks from same domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I manage a schools computers that the students are using. Since its kids that are using them I need to restrict them somehow.
We are using Chromebooks with our own Google domain.

Is it possible to create a list with blocked URLs in a google spreadsheet and then run a script that update the settings for every OU in our domain (or the ones that I choses) with our blocked URLs?

So far I havent found anything that is pointing me in the right direction

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/orgunits

Comment: I've read that before but couldnt see anything that would help me. Is there a specific part that you think I should read?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61279055/1595451